# Unable to boot into recovery mode on El Capitan MacBook Air

Tags: macos, startup, recovery

I want to disable System Integrity Protection, So i am trying to run this command `csrutil disable` On recovery mode, But i am not able to boot in Recovery mode, It keep showing user login screen, I tried to Hold this Command+R combination as well as Command+E+R till The Apple logo shows, But no luck.

This the output of `diskutil list` command
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to boot into internet recovery (from Apple servers). Ensure a stable internet connection. You can then run `csrutil disable` in the terminal.

As far as your recovery partition. If it is truly not working, you can delete the partition, download the latest OS X installer from the App Store and then reinstall OS X (this will not delete your files, think of it just like an OS X update). As part of the OS X reinstall, it will add a fresh new recovery partition.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @klanomath Thanks for the comment, I did not know that. Will edit above.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, But its also not working... , it keep showing the User login screen.. :(

Comment: @Salim Just to cover all bases, when do you start holding down the keys on restart?

Comment: @Salim Also, how old is your Mac?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, So i shut down the system, then press and hold cmd+r, or cmd+option+r then switch on the system, i keep holding it till the apple Logo shows, That is one thing i tried, another one i tried is to switch on the system immediately press and hold those key combination, Its only 9 days old.. :) .

Comment: @Salim That is strange for such a new Mac. Your method is correct. If you're up for it, try removing your recovery partition using `diskutil mergePartitions` (read the man page  `man diskutil` carefully and backup before hand). You will want to merge `disk0s2` with `disk0s3` (assuming the output you posted above remains true), the second one (a.k.a. the recovery partition) is reformatted but Machintosh HD should remain intact and expand to take up the space. Verify the merge was successful with `diskutil list`. Then reinstall OS X as suggested above, and try recovery again. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, So i had talk with apple Support, They told to show it at a service centar, I will let you know once i done that..

Answer (score 1):

Solved (for my particular situation anyway): I was suspicious that my machine (2009 Mac Pro) wouldn't recognize the keyboard through an external monitor. So I pulled the USB from my monitor, plugged it directly into the desktop, and lo-and-behold, Command+r allowed the machine to boot into recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. The only way I could enter recovery mode was to shutdown, press and hold Command+Option+R and then press the power button.

Comment: There are multiple ways to enter Recovery Mode depending on your intention. Command+R will let you install the latest version of macOS without upgrading your Mac. Command+Option+R will upgrade you to the latest MacOS your Mac supports. Shift+Command+Option+T will install your Mac's original MacOS if available.